# using a dictionary to parse a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary of words from a questionnaire:

```
mydict = {'CP4 MPI(SF) throbbing [mild]':'throbbing mild',
CP4 MPI(SF) thobbing [moderate]':'throbbing moderate',....}
```

my csv file has numerous columns - that correspond to the keys in mydict, rows represent study participants.

if a row (a study participant) responded yes to a question, there is a 1 in that particular field of the csv file

the values contained within mydict are abbreviations of the persons response that I would like to save in a new list

I would like to parse a csv file using this dictionary as follows:

(using csv.DictReader)

```
mcgill = []

mcgill_sf = {'CP4 MPI(SF) | Throbbing [Mild]':'throbbing mild', 'CP4 
             MPI(SF) | Throbbing [Moderate]':'throbbing moderate', 'CP4 
             MPI(SF) | Throbbing [Severe]':'throbbing severe', 'CP4 
             MPI(SF) | Shooting[Mild]':'shooting mild'}

x = mcgill_sf.keys()
if row[x] == '1':
    y = mcgill_sf[key]
    mcgill.append(y)
print(mcgill)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "triage_1200.py", line 401, in <module>
    if row[x] == '1':
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'
```

I can't determine how to work with keys / values within the dict to achieve this objective... can anyone advise?

Comment: Uhhhh `x = mydict[key]`?

Comment: Um, do you really expect people to decipher that? **update your question with code and use formatting**

Comment: thanks - new at this! forgive my rough start...

Comment: `x = mcgill_sf.keys()` returns a view of the keys. I am unsure what you are expecting it to return. Please try to provide a [mcve] or else it becomes very difficult to figure out what you are trying to do

Comment: yes - that is correct - my problem is in parsing the csv file. if a row within the csv file of column x contains a '1' a new list is appended with the value paired to the x key - however, it seems I can't use a dictionary to parse a csv file ??

Comment: Again, please provide a [mcve]. Use toy data, because I am having a hard time following you. To parse a csv, you should use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). It's designed for dealing with datasets such as these.